# Azure Mobile Services with Websocket

Tags: node.js, azure, websocket, azure-mobile-services

I would like to use websocket to notify a remote website whenever a table insert is triggered on my Azure mobile services.

Right now I was able to successfully send GCM notification to registered device using

```
push.gcm.send
```

in my insert script.

If i want to achieve aforementioned requirement, what are the required steps?
Setup a Node.js server, call node.js server from insert script, then node.js server use websocket to connect with remote website?

Please kindly point me to the right direction.

thanks!

Comment: Could you please specify your need? When the insert operation is triggered, your mobile service backend in Node.js send a message to another website or web server? Do you have to use websocket, or whatever can be used just to approach your requirement?

Comment: Hi @GaryLiu-MSFT, our need is to be able to send notification to different platforms in real time once insert is triggered. Right now we use Notification Hub + GCM but it has limitation that only Android/Chrome/iOS can be received,

Comment: and GCM is not real time. GCM is fine for sending to mobile devices, but we would like to support other platforms such as website, IoT devices. All my search convinced me to use websocket.

Comment: Per my understanding, to simplify the scenario, mobile users insert data in application , and that also will show up on the website for those non-application users?

Comment: Yes, but the recipient is not limited to website.
It could be Firefox extension, Safari Extension, Win 7 software.
Which is why I believe websocket is needed because it is cross-platform.

Comment: @GaryLiu-MSFT Even if Leo adds a dependency on a node package that let him use Websockets, he might face a problem finding an open TCP port.  I couldn't find a list of the open ports for Mobile Services except for port 443 of course.

Comment: I thought of a workaround maybe can approach your need. We can build a website on Azure Web apps as a websocket server. There are 2 branches: 1,Create an HTTP API on websocket server, when the trigger is triggered, the mobile service hit the API send msg to the server, and the server broadcast via websocket. 2, leverage Storage Queue. When the trigger is triggered, push msg on queue, and in Web Apps, we can create a web job to get msg from queue continuous. Get more: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-bus-azure-and-service-bus-queues-compared-contrasted/

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use Socket.IO with Azure Mobile Services: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/how-to-use-socket-io-with-azure-mobile-service-node-backend/

The comment posted by @gary-liu-msft is also good idea, using queues. He pointed here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/how-to-use-socket-io-with-azure-mobile-service-node-backend/